# Hibernate : the double reference of an entity causes incorrect generation of the LoadQueryDetails object

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I everyone

I have a bad request generated by hibernate/jpa
I have relations like this

Lieu -> (1,* LAZY) Salle -> (1,* LAZY) Equipement

Lieu -> (1,* EAGER) Equipement

when I'm loading a Lieu object, a request to query Lieu and Equipement is running but this request used a bad "path".

```
select lieu0_.id as id1_2_0_, lieu0_.description as descript2_2_0_, lieu0_.published as publishe3_2_0_, lieu0_.title as title4_2_0_, equipement1_.lieufk as lieufk3_1_1_, equipement1_.id as id1_1_1_, equipement1_.id as id1_1_2_, equipement1_.lieufk as lieufk3_1_2_, equipement1_.sallefk as sallefk4_1_2_, equipement1_.type as type2_1_2_, salle2_.id as id1_0_3_, salle2_.lieufk as lieufk2_3_3_, salle2_.type as type1_3_3_, lieu3_.id as id1_2_4_, lieu3_.description as descript2_2_4_, lieu3_.published as publishe3_2_4_, lieu3_.title as title4_2_4_ from lieu lieu0_ left outer join equipement equipement1_ on lieu0_.id=equipement1_.lieufk left outer join salle salle2_ on equipement1_.sallefk=salle2_.id left outer join lieu lieu3_ on salle2_.lieufk=lieu3_.id where lieu0_.id=?
```

where clause is

```
from lieu lieu0_ left outer join equipement equipement1_ on lieu0_.id=equipement1_.lieufk left outer join salle salle2_ on equipement1_.sallefk=salle2_.id left outer join lieu lieu3_ on salle2_.lieufk=lieu3_.id
```

**equipement -> salle -> lieu** instead of **equipement -> lieu**

After a while I found maybe where this "path error" is created

During hibernate/JPA init sequence in AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer class line 61 and 62 these instruction was executed

```
finalLoadPlan plan =MetamodelDrivenLoadPlanBuilder.buildRootCollectionLoadPlan( strategy, collectionPersister );
this.staticLoadQuery =BatchingLoadQueryDetailsFactory.INSTANCE.makeCollectionLoadQueryDetails( collectionPersister, plan, buildingParameters );
```

When building collectionPersister OneToManyPersister for Lieu.equipements collection

this.staticLoadQuery should contain a query to load equipment from Lieu like this one

```
select equipement0_.sallefk as sallefk4_1_0_, equipement0_.id as id1_1_0_, equipement0_.id as id1_1_1_, equipement0_.lieufk as lieufk3_1_1_, equipement0_.sallefk as sallefk4_1_1_, equipement0_.type as type2_1_1_, lieu1_.id as id1_2_2_, lieu1_.description as descript2_2_2_, lieu1_.published as publishe3_2_2_, lieu1_.title as title4_2_2_ from equipement equipement0_ inner join lieu lieu1_ on equipement0_.lieufk=lieu1_.id where equipement0_.lieufk=?
```

But a query passing by table lieu → salle → equipement like this one is generated

```
select equipement0_.lieufk as lieufk3_1_0_, equipement0_.id as id1_1_0_, equipement0_.id as id1_1_1_, equipement0_.lieufk as lieufk3_1_1_, equipement0_.sallefk as sallefk4_1_1_, equipement0_.type as type2_1_1_, salle1_.id as id1_0_2_, salle1_.code_user_to_create as code_use2_0_2_, salle1_.code_user_to_update as code_use3_0_2_, salle1_.date_crea_enr as date_cre4_0_2_, salle1_.date_modif_enr as date_mod5_0_2_, salle1_.temoin_en_service as temoin_e6_0_2_, salle1_.lieufk as lieufk2_3_2_, salle1_.type as type1_3_2_, lieu2_.id as id1_2_3_, lieu2_.description as descript2_2_3_, lieu2_.published as publishe3_2_3_, lieu2_.title as title4_2_3_ from equipement equipement0_ inner join salle salle1_ on equipement0_.sallefk=salle1_.id inner join lieu lieu2_ on salle1_.lieufk=lieu2_.id where equipement0_.lieufk=?
```

the declaration of my model seems good

I have the impression that the loadPlan doesn't seem to match the joint declaration

To reproduce the case :

- download project https://github.com/arnaudbarbe/spring-hibernate-bug
- run the test and you will see the "bad" request
- put breakpoint in AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer class line 61
- run in debug the test class SpringBootJpaH2ApplicationTests.

Comment: I've done some modifications into the github projet, especially in test class. Now the test hang on bad request.